Hyperlink column not working as button
I have SharePoint list which adds the item based on the flow, however the column hyperlink is not working as a button. But when initially created the list it was working but now it is not.
{"_comment":"A button to open a hyperlink","$schema":"https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json","elmType":"a","attributes":{"class":"ms-fontColor-white ms-fontColor-red--hover","href":"='URL' + [$MYNUMBER]","target":"_blank)"},"style":{"border":"none","cursor":"pointer","background-color":"transparent","display":"=if([$MYNUMBER] == '','none','flex')"},"children":[{"elmType":"div","attributes":{"class":""},"style":{"font-size":"14px","font-family":"arial","border":"1px solid Black","border-radius":"=if(1==1,'7px','0px')","box-shadow":"=if(1==1,'2px 2px #999','none')","padding":"3px 5px 3px 5px"},"children":[{"elmType":"div","attributes":{"iconName":""},"style":{"display":"=if('' != '','inline-block','none')","vertical-align":"middle","padding-right":"5px"}},{"elmType":"div","txtContent":"=if('' != '',' ' + 'GOTO SFT' + [$MYNUMBER], ' ' + 'GOTO SFT' + [$MYNUMBER])","style":{"display":"inline-block","font-family":"arial","vertical-align":"middle"}}]}]}




What is the issue exactly? Is hyperlink/button not shown correctly or is it not opening the URL on click or is the opened URL wrong?

The hyperlink/button is not opening the URL on click in new tab. The action is the Hyperlink column should open the "URL+Title" link in new tab.

Is "URL" part hardcoded or is it another column in same SharePoint list?

@GaneshSanap-MVP The "URL" part is hardcoded

I just tried using below SharePoint JSON column formatting and it works fine for me:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "ms-fontColor-white ms-fontColor-red--hover",
    "href": "='https://www.google.com/search?q=' + [$MYNUMBER]",
    "target": "_blank)"
  },
  "style": {
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "background-color": "transparent",
    "display": "=if([$MYNUMBER] == '','none','flex')"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": ""
      },
      "style": {
        "font-size": "14px",
        "font-family": "arial",
        "border": "1px solid Black",
        "border-radius": "=if(1==1,'7px','0px')",
        "box-shadow": "=if(1==1,'2px 2px #999','none')",
        "padding": "3px 5px 3px 5px"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "iconName": ""
          },
          "style": {
            "display": "=if('' != '','inline-block','none')",
            "vertical-align": "middle",
            "padding-right": "5px"
          }
        },
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "txtContent": "=if('' != '',' ' + 'GOTO SFT' + [$MYNUMBER], ' ' + 'GOTO SFT' + [$MYNUMBER])",
          "style": {
            "display": "inline-block",
            "font-family": "arial",
            "vertical-align": "middle"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Output:

Note:

Make sure you are using correct internal name of your columns in the JSON. In above JSON, [$MYNUMBER] should be an internal name of your column in SharePoint list in this format: [$InternalNameOfColumn]. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?.

Documentation: SharePoint JSON formatting - Turn field values into hyperlinks (basic).

Yes i have validated the internal name it is correct indeed, but still when i click on the GOTOSFT10 it not opening URL in new tab.

Very strange, I tried above JSON and it works fine for me. Are you using SharePoint online or SharePoint server (2019)? Please check if you are missing any = or '' characters in JSON somewhere in expressions which might cause this issue.

I am also wondering how come it is not working, It is SharePoint Online. I have reused exact same json which you have provided and just replaced the URL. I have migrated this list from tenant to tenant. Would that cost any problem here ?

Can you share a screenshot where are you adding this JSON exactly? Maybe it will help me to understand if any issue related to this.

I have added the screenshot to the main question. When i try to access the link from list using inspect the link is working, but when onclick to hyperlink column it is not working

What I have observed now is that, if tries to click on the button it is not working but if tried to click outside button or next to the blank space it is working. Sounds bit weird to open link in new tab. Did something changed in the SharePoint list behavior ?

For me it is working fine inside the button as well. For your case, you will have to inspect the a element in JSON properly and see what is the width/position allocated to it in the DOM elements and make sure it has proper width & position inside the button/borders.

Are you opening this list in "SharePoint" UI or do you see it opened in "Microsoft Lists" UI? I have seen few people complaining about JSON formatting is not working properly in "Microsoft Lists" UI.

In my case it is both. SharePoint UI and MS List UI both have the same behavior. I am using the same JSON as i have mentioned in the main question with no changes. And Also tried yours seems like both have the same way working intensions.

I also just discovered a Column Formatting that worked in the past and just stopped working recently.
I think something has been changed by Microsoft or whoever (I am not an expert)
I can also only click a button outside of it's boundaries to get referred to the URL
